# Stores and Dataview List - Can't Add Element - IndexOf of null

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Using Sencha Touch (2.2) with Sencha Architect 2

I have a tree structure in which I navigate.

The nodes are Elements and elements can either be a folder or a leaf.

To display the elements on my Ext.dataview.dataview (LIST), I use a store (storeID: 'elementstore') and Ext.dataview.component.Dataitem.

Here is my code to fill the LIST at first and everytime we open a folder to go deeper in the tree.

> Filling the store for the first time, disable event so update() is not
>   called twice has I will be switching to this view right after the
>   creation of it. It works well and give back the desired result. I have
>   in my LIST the first level of Folders and Leaf displayed.
>
> This is fired directly in the list with an onItemTap Event

```
var EStore = Ext.getStore('elementstore');
EStore.removeAll();
EStore.suspendEvents();
EStore.add(record.get('arrElement'));
EStore.resumeEvents(true);
```

> Emptying and refilling the store with the reached level of the tree.
>
> This is fired directly in the LIST with an onItemTap Event

```
if(record.get('strUIType') === 'folder')
    {
        INDEX_STACK.push(index);
        store = Ext.getStore('elementstore');
        store.removeAll();
        store.add(record.get('arrElement'));
    }
```

> What is wrong is when I try to go backward, going up in my tree.  Here
>   is the code which is located in a Sencha Controller.
>
> It actually does not go back one level but back at the top level.  ACTIVE_PROJECT is the
>   index of the active tree which are all located in my project store.

```
var popped =INDEX_STACK.pop();
var tab = tabpanel.getParent().getParent().getParent().getComponent('projects_Tab');

if(popped === undefined)
{
    tab.setActiveItem(0);
}
else
{
    var eStore = Ext.getStore('elementstore');
    eStore.removeAll();

    //Crashes!
    eStore.add(Ext.getStore('projectstore').getAt(ACTIVE_PROJECT).get('arrElement'));
}
```

Has you see the eStore.add(....) is the crashing line on which I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null sencha-touch-all.js:21
Ext.Array.contains.e 
Ext.Array.include 
Ext.define.join 
Ext.define.insert 
Ext.define.add 
Ext.define.onMain_TabsTap  (----Yep this line is my code the rest is sencha touch...
Ext.define.doFire
```

The only thing I achieve to add to the store in this controller is an empty Ext.create(CarboZero.model.Element).  I can not get anything from my active project.

Is there something wrong with removing and readding? Is my store getting corrupted from how I'm using it? I have been working on that for about 2 days without getting anything to work properly...

**EDIT TO THE QUESTION**

I just set in my Element store the destroyRemovedRecords to FALSE.

Everything works, but I don't understand ANYTHING on why it corrected the problem with my particular structure...  WHat is the remove() doing exactly???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set Element store's property to the following

```
destroyRemovedRecords : false
```

Solve the problem, still can't explain why.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. As with all Sencha bugs, finding a solution to obscure junk that just seems to randomly happen within the framework is really difficult. This helped me solve the exact same problem.

Comment: Take a look at my profile, it's full of those (Internship on sencha and I never had done any)

Comment: Seems to work in ST2.3.1 as well. Makes no sense at all though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the caching became full. On the leaf models, you could set `useCache: false` to prevent the data to get cached. That fixed my issue.